# Word crashes after Office Update KB4462178

Tags: com, office-interop, office-addins, outlook-redemption, addin-express

My COM-Addin is already 4 years old, has about 2k users daily, and some users who use Office 365, after applying the Office update KB4462178 released last week, sometimes causes Word CRASH to open.

I've removed my Addin's business codes, has isolated the routines, read everything I found about the KB4462178 and sometimes the error happens.

There is no logic in generating the error. Why, the same dlls that sometimes generate the error, work sometimes. I have no idea what it can be.
I have reviewed Event Viewer, Addin-Express Logs, My Addin Logs and everything seems to work correctly.

I have already uninstalled and installed Office again several times, at first it works, after a short time it returns the error.

When you open Word and you click the blank Word crashes Template. I noticed the same behavior in Excel and Power Point. But in Outlook, it works normally.

I'm using Procmon.exe, but I have not yet identified what causes the error. Any other tool I could be using?

Something I noticed is that the splash screen of Word looks different when the error will occur. When the error occurs it looks like this:
[image: Word will crashe]

And when it will work, it looks like this:
[image: When the templates are correctly loaded its works fine]

What could be causing this error? I'm out of ideas. It only happens with Office 365 with version 1905 build 11629.20246

Is it happening to anyone else? It's a VSTO COM Addin, I'm using Addin-Express, Outlook Redemption, DevExpress and it generally works fine.

Comment: It appears as if Office isn't able to access on-line content when the crashes occur. You might ask in an end-user venue if anyone knows about the connection between the update and the missing icons/links across the top - without mentioning your program. Anyway, I expect the problem does not lie with your code, specifically, but with the fact that Office isn't "ready" to do whatever the code is asking it to do. Since you don't provide a [mcve] it's not possible make any analysis beyond that...

Comment: @CindyMeister thank you for your reply. I will try to prepare some example, but this is really crazy. Sometimes it works nicely and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: Have you tried to capture the crash dump using procdump.exe?

Comment: Yes, We used ProcMonitor.

Comment: @AndersonRissardi have you found a solution for this,

Comment: Yes, see the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have found the bug.

```
private static string GetQtdadeMemoriaEmUso()
    {
        try
        {
            var obj = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");
            return obj.NextValue() + " Mb";
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            return "Não foi possível buscar a quantidade de memória em uso. Erro: " + err.Message + "\r\nStack: " + err.StackTrace;
        }
    }
```

The problem is inside the "System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter" Class.
Even using the try/catch, the exception occurs internally.

We believe that with this new "security update" from Microsoft something goes wrong sometimes.

We dont have any idea about what can be causing the error sometimes only. Its really, really strange.